# How to force reload a back button press when some elements are updated via Ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, browser-cache

My rails website has mainly two pages both of which render a single template along with some other views corresponding to each page. Something like this

**Page #1**

```
<%= view belonging to controller_one action_one %>

<%= render template: "common_template from another controller" %>
```

**Page #2**

```
<%= view belonging to controller_one action_two %>

<%= render template: "common_template from another controller" %>
```

The thing is, I go from Page #1 to Page #2 and update the elements of

```
"common_template from another controller"
```

via Ajax. So, when I press the back button, no request is made to the server and elements in Page #1 are not updated. I'm guessing that the browser is caching the webpage to display without changing anything. If that's the case, how can I force the page to reload when the back button is pressed and all elements are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have turbolinks enabled? If this is the case, that is causing the page to be cached for sure.

You can remove it from application.js to test and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tried it.The page now reloads for every request, but the page is still cached and back button problem is not solved still. Tried in incognito mode too. Should I disable caching ?